# Docker image build

Tags: docker

I am facing issue while giving build in docker.getting error build docker images.in Linux server

Error (internal) load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8

I tried to restart server and free space from server still it's not working.

Comment: Hi, may be you attach more information about building docker? code, set of commands?  What docker did you do?

Comment: Hi I am trying to build images . After entering command --    (docker image build -t roster.) It's throwing error  like fail to solved :java:8dockrer.io/library/java:8:

Comment: Have you tried to make a search with this error message as recommended in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `sudo vi  ~/.docker/config.json`

Update following Block:

```
{
      "credsStore": "desktop.exe"
}
```

Here, Change from **credsStore** to **credStore**

> Run your services `docker-compose up your-services`

Comment: OP said they want to build an image, not deploy a compose-stack. The answer is also highly speculative; I see nothing in the post that suggests that there is a typo in the docker configuration.

Comment: Although It's accepted answer